# Getting Unexpected out with java Collections

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections, hashmap

If i compare the firstList element with compare method then working fine, it's giving true, but if i compare the secondList element with compare method then not working, it's giving false

```
//**Working case**

List<String> firstList  = new ArrayList();
firstList .add("1111111111");
firstList .add("1111333333");
firstList .add("2222224444");
firstList .add("9999888888");

// sout(firstList) :  [1111111111, 1111333333, 2222224444, 9999888888]
*System.out.println("first list :::  "+firstList.contains("2222224444")); // true*
// Here i am getting true as expected


// **Not working case** - here final output expected is true but i am getting as false

Map<String,String> elements = new HashMap();

elements.put("user_dids",firstList .toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));

// sout(elements.get("user_dids")) :  1111111111, 1111333333, 2222224444, 9999888888

List<String> secondList = Arrays.asList(elements.get("user_dids"));

//sout(secondList) : [1111111111, 1111333333, 2222224444, 9999888888]

System.out.println(" Second List ::: "+secondList.contains("2222224444")); // false*

// Second list getting false for contains method, but it needs to get true
```

For the first ArrayList I am getting true for contains Method, but in the second Arraylist also need to get true for contains method but - I am getting false.

Comment: Can any one please help why i am getting false for secondList

Comment: I wonder if it's because spaces need to be trimmed in your call to toString()

Comment: Print the secondList using System.out.println to check whether list has those eements or not. I doubt secondList does not have that String.

Comment: The second list has only one element in it, the string `1111111111, 1111333333, 2222224444, 9999888888`. `secondList.contains()` checks if one element is *equal to* `2222224444`, which your element isn’t, so it returns false.

Comment: `elements.get(...)` returns a `String`, and `Arrays.asList(s)` returns a list of one element. Why did you believe that the list would have more than one element in it?

Answer (score 2):

You secondList has only one element which is "1111111111, 1111333333, 2222224444, 9999888888", this is not same as "2222224444"

Comment: List<String> secondList = Arrays.asList( elements.get("user_dids").split(",")); Now i have written like this even though it's getting false.

Comment: @SrikanthJanapati Try `split(", ")` with a space after the comma.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for update with this change working fine, in the list i am getting comma with space , so by spiting with comma(,) and space it's working fine.

Comment: Glad that it works, @SrikanthJanapati Why you want to convert your list to a string and back into a list I have not understood.